# Controlling Access to Class Members

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
   private:
           int x;
   public:
           virtual void show()
           {
               cout<<"X: "<<x;
           }
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
           virtual void show()
           {
               cout<<"In class B\n";
               A::show();
           }
};
```

My question is about accessibility from a member function. In this example, can we say that member function of B (show() of B) can access X in the class A.

Answer (score 2):

Since `x` is declared `private` in `A`, nothing in `B` can directly access it.  Of course, it can be accessed indirectly -- `B` can call `A::show()` which can access `x`.  But `B::show()` cannot access `x`, nor can anything else in `B`.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you meant that calling A::show() in B::show() is not considered accessing X by using a member function of class B. Am I wright?

Comment: Correct.  It is not, because nothing defined in `B` writes a value to `x` or reads a value from `x` (nor can it).

Answer (score 2):

You are not really accessing `A.x`, you are accessing `A.show()`.

To answer your question, `B::show()` is **not** accessing the private member `x` in `A`.

The reason for this is, `class A` can change the function `A::show()` and do something else, and `B` can just call `A::show()`.

This is the main point of encapsulation. You can tell A to do *things* (like `show()`), but `A` decides how to do them.

Answer (score 0):

1. A::show() can access any member variables in it's own class, class A.
2. Member functions in class B can access any public or protected member *variables* in class A.
   and
3. Member functions in class B can access any public of protected member *functions* in class A.

2 and 3 are possible because the "Most accessible level" of A is defined as public.

```
Class B: public A
```

In your code, specifically, the accessibility level of `int x;` doesn't matter, because it is never directly accessed from class B.